# Reason behind cancelling Death sentence

Tags: law, death-penalty

Two of Delhi (India) gang rape criminal's death sentences are suspended,

From Justice Verma's Report:

> 'The Verma Committee favoured comprehensive amendments to criminal
>   laws seeking minimum 20 years imprisonment for gang rape and life term
>   for rape and murder but refrained from prescribing death penalty.'

Now, what is the reason behind cancelling death penalty in Verma's report?

From what I read it is a barbaric act and hence denied. However are there any other reasons for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They considered 37 points, some for some against, among them were the USA's interpretation that it constituted "cruel and unusual punishment," to be in accordance with UN General Assembly Resolution 65/206, and '**rarest of rare**’ has required giving ‘special reasons’ before imposing a penalty as specified under Section 354 (1).

You can read the full Report of the Committee on Amendments to Criminal Law](http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/archive/01340/Justice_Verma_Comm_1340438a.pdf) here. It's purpose specifically was (page 2)

> to look into possible amendments to the Criminal Law to provide for quicker trial and enhanced punishment for criminals committing sexual assault of extreme nature against women.

Of particular interest is the section on **SENTENCING AND PUNISHMENT**, on the death penalty, page 252-263 of the pdf (labeled 240-251).

> 37). Thus, there is a strong case which is made out before us that in India in the context of **international law** as well as the law as explained in the **American Courts**, it would be **a regressive step to introduce death penalty for rape** even where such punishment is restricted to the rarest of rare cases. It is also stated that there is considerable evidence that the deterrent effect of death penalty on serious crimes is actually a myth. According to the Working Group on Human Rights, the murder rate has declined consistently in India over the last 20 years despite the slowdown in the execution of death sentences since 1980. Hence we do take note of the argument that introduction of death penalty for rape may not have a deterrent effect.

The "quote" you have slightly off (page 457 pdf, 444 as printed):

> **376D. Gang Rape followed by death or a persistent vegetative state**
>
> Whoever commits gang rape, and in the course of such commission inflicts injury upon the victim which causes the victim’s death or causes the victim to be in a persistent vegetative state, shall be punished with imprisonment for life.

The [Delhi gran grape and murder](http://ibnlive.in.com/news/delhi-gangrapemurder-case-full-text-of-the-verdict/421751-3-244.html) verdict used the 'rarest of rare' doctorine to sentence the defendants to death. Their sentence was appealed, but even without these new reduced penalties under the law, India [hasn't executed](http://blogs.wsj.com/indiarealtime/2013/09/13/death-penalty-what-is-the-rarest-of-rare/) many people on [their death row](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-20708007).

> According to Death Penalty Worldwide, created by Sandra Babcock, a professor at Northwestern University Law School in Chicago, India executed 140 people a year between 1954 and 1962. Since 2004, India has carried out only three executions, with two taking place within the past year.

Comment: would india use the death penalty in similar cases to this one given the doctorine ? also how do death penalty moritariums work ?